# How to add a responsive tab menu and shrink li menu item Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

My website has mega drop-down menu which is built on twitter bootstrap.

I tried to add a tabbed menu, which is not bootstrap buil but responsive, to my mega drop down item.

However, it doesn't fit there well and it wrap whole toggle.

This is how I add a full width mega dropdown.

```
<li class="dropdown full-width"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">TEST<b
        class="icon-angle-down"></b></a>
</li>
```

Here you can **[VIEW](http://www.carantina.com)** the demo page

When you hover on item on the navbar 'ILETISIM', it toggles full width, which I exactly want. Because I built it with twitter bootstrap

[image]

However, please check the item **'TEST'**. The script that I added later is not twitter bootstrap built, but responsive and it breaks the navbar and makes the item's **li** full width as shown in the picture below.

[image]

I couldn't find any solutions for that until now.

What I want is, it shall behave as same as how 'ILETISIM' item works.

I will replace that menu with the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap zozo tabs in a div and give it 100% with like so:

```
<div class="tab-wrapper dropdown-menu">
 zozo tabs here....
</div>
```

The rest of the issue is related to twitter nav menu. The sub menu show on hover which is inside ul and you have added zozo tabs inside a div.

```
/*hide by default*/
.tab-wrapper{
    display: none;
    width: 980px; 
    left: -492.5px;
}
/*display on hover sub menu*/
.navbar ul.nav li:hover > .tab-wrapper {
    display: block;
}
```

Now there will be some issue with default tab since the whole elements display is set to none.

**Update**:
added class tab-wrapper and replaced the css style.

**Update 2**
I realized that your menu is absolute positioned. So added the same class the to div dropdown-menu which will make it absolute from your style and added some more style.

**Update 3**
The mobile dropdown menu shows up because it the element or its container is hidden with display none. We use the refresh method after its visible.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
         /*give your li id of test and it fire on mouseover to refresh the tabs*/
        $("#test").on("mouseover", function () {
            $("#tabbed-nav-02").data('zozoTabs').refresh();
        });
    });
```

Also could you add tags zozo-tabs and zozo-ui to your stackoverflow post?

Comment: I gave it but it doesn't work. What I am trying to achieve is when my cursor is on 'TEST' , the toggle shall be opened which your Zozo Tabs,

Now as you can see on the website, It toggles as default. It shall open when my mouse is over 'TEST'.

Comment: I checked it and it is hidden. When now it doesn't toggle. It shall toggle when my cursor is on 'TEST'. Just check the item 'ILETISIM' it will behave the same.

Comment: Now it toggles right. However, your menu is like in the mobile. It behaves like that area is smaller and shrinks the content since it is responsible. There must be a simple solution for this.

Comment: BTW I just checked I couldn't add zozo-tabs 'Creating the new tag 'zozo-tabs' requires at least 1500 reputation. Try something from the existing tags list instead.'